# Find the order of the matrices $A$ and Matrice $B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find  the   order of the  matrices $A$ and $B$ in the Group $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_7)$: $$A=\begin{bmatrix}  1 &1 \\ 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}\;\text{and}\; B=\begin{bmatrix}  2 &0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

For $A$ I take  $
\pmatrix{1&x\\0&1}\pmatrix{1&y\\0&1}=\pmatrix{1&x+y\\0&1}\,,
$
and

for $ B$ we have 
$
\pmatrix{a&0\\0&1}\pmatrix{b&0\\0&1}=\pmatrix{ab&0\\0&1}\,.
$

After that  im not able to proceed  further ,

any hints/solution

thanks in advance

Comment: For $A$, use what you've observed and think about when $x+y=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_7$. For $B$, use what you've observed and think about when $2^n=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_7$.

Comment: @symlectomorphic i observed 4+3 = 0

Comment: ... But you need to find $n$ such that $A^n=I$, the identity matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your matrix $A$, we have $$\begin{pmatrix}1 &1 \\0 &1 \end{pmatrix}^n=\begin{pmatrix}1 &n \\0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$$

so, we have to find a least $n$ for which $$\begin{pmatrix}1 &n \\0 &1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 &0 \\0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$$ Now, clearly for $n=1,2,\cdots,6$ it does't happen but in the seventh power it becomes identity.

So $$\text{order of}\;\begin{pmatrix}1 &1 \\0 &1 \end{pmatrix}=7$$

In general order of $\begin{pmatrix}1 &1 \\0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$ in $GL(2,\Bbb{Z}_p)$ is $p$ where $p$ is prime

Similarly work for the second matrix